# Optimal method for organizing videos by topics discussed?

Tags: videos, vimeo

We have a couple hundred (and growing weekly) videos that are all live 1-2 hour Zoom meetings hosted on Vimeo.  Currently our members can log into our site and access all the videos which are organized by a handful of very-high-level categories.

The trouble is that each video can cover a number of topics, and it's hard for members to figure out from the titles alone, which videos talk about topics X or Y.  We want to find a way to help the members find the meetings that are relevant to specific topics, but short of going back and watching every single one of them ourselves, manually taking copious notes with timestamps and maintaining a constantly growing list of timestamps into the future, I'm not sure what an optimal approach to this would be.

Is there some way we could add meta data to the videos, and link people directly to a dynamically-generated list/gallery of the videos related to their desired topic?  They would still have to manually navigate to the timestamps where their point of interest was discussed I suppose, but at least it would reduce the universe of videos they're looking through in that moment from a couple hundred or more, to maybe a dozen or two.

Could really use some suggestions if anyone has had to tackle something like this before.

Comment: Since you're hosting the videos on Vimeo, not actually adding them to the Media Library, I don't think you would have any way of adding metadata to them. You would have to be serving them from your own site, and then look into plugins that enable metadata on Media Library items.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much, was more thinking if somehow the metadata could get added separately and associated to each video.  Kinda sounds like a management nightmare though.

Comment: You could create a CPT that accepts the Vimeo URL as well as the metadata (or ideally taxonomies since they're much faster to search by), then build a custom search that utilizes the taxonomies/meta. Then you'd want to ensure you have a template that embeds the video on the individual CPTs.